# Android testing onActivityResult errors with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I have a fragment in my activity, that it will get some data on its `onActivityResult()`, And try to update the UI. This is my `onActivityResult()` code:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {

            GET_USER_AUDIO_TO_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE -> {

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    data?.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)?.let {
                    val receivedCityName = it[0]
                    binding.homeCityNameEditTextView.setText(receivedCityName)//Update UI at this line
                    viewModel.fetchWeatherCity(receivedCityName)
                }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.error_while_getting_data_from_recognizer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So I tried to create some Instrumentation test with the Espresso for this part as bellow:

```
 @Test
 fun checkActionsAfterReceivingDataInOnActivityResult() {

        val intent = Intent()
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS, arrayListOf(DEFAULT_CITY_NAME))

        activityRule.activity.supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentByTag(HomeFragment.CLASS_NAME)
                ?.onActivityResult(
                        HomeFragment.GET_USER_AUDIO_TO_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE,
                        Activity.RESULT_OK,
                        intent
                )

    }
```

But I will get an error after running this `Test method` that says:
This error is because of my `ViewModel` methods that will run. by calling this line in onActivityResult():

```
viewModel.fetchWeatherCity(receivedCityName)
```

This is its error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread
at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.assertMainThread(LiveData.java:435)
at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:279)
```

And because of updating my UI by this line:

```
binding.homeCityNameEditTextView.setText(receivedCityName)//Update UI at this line
```

I will get this error too:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Comment: Use `postValue` instead of `setValue` to update `liveData of a viewModel` when its running on a `different thread`

Comment: My ViewModel works fine, And actually I'm not working on background threads!
Just when I want to run the mentioned UI test, I will get this kind of error.

Comment: I have updated the answer please check !

Answer (score 1):

`Test instrumentation` runs on a different thread, so wrap up the `test method-body with run on UI thread`.

```
activityRule.activity.runOnUiThread {
  // the test method body goes in here 
}
```

In your case:-

```
activityRule.activity.runOnUiThread {
   activityRule.activity.supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentByTag(HomeFragment.CLASS_NAME)
                ?.onActivityResult(
                        HomeFragment.GET_USER_AUDIO_TO_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE,
                        Activity.RESULT_OK,
                        intent)
}
```

Comment: is that ok to handle it like that?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't invoke methods such as `onActivityResult` directly in your Espresso test. You will always get the same error because these tests are executed on different threads. If you want to test it correctly, you should consider using [Espresso-Intents](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents):

```
@Test
fun checkActionsAfterReceivingDataInOnActivityResult() {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS, arrayListOf(DEFAULT_CITY_NAME))

    intending(hasComponent(YourActivity.class.getName())).respondWith(ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent))

    // onView(...).perform(click())
    // First do something to cause your app to launch the intended activity

    // onView(...).check(matches(...))
    // Then test something on activity result
}
```